# Sonatype Nexus can't index IBM Maven repository

Tags: maven, ibm-rad, sonatype, maven-indexer

We're trying to proxy the IBM Maven repository on our company internal Sonatype Nexus. We added the repository address but the repo has not been populated even under direct request.

The Sonatype nexus' "Browse Index" tab is empty whereas the "Browse Remote" correctly shows the library tree. But when adding dependecies to a project's pom.xml file, the IDE says it cannot find the archetypes and the artifacts.

Is the IBM repository indexed? Is there something we're missing? We are using IBM RAD 9.5 and Sonatype Nexus™ 2.11.4-01

Comment: Do other repositories work fine? Did you maybe forget to add the IBM repository to the "public" group or whatever are you mirroring with your settings.xml?

Comment: Yes, other repositories are working fine and the IBM repository belongs to the public repositories group.

Comment: What is the URL for the IBM Maven repository? I did't think they published their jars publicly in maven.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Maven repositories do not publish search indexes, they are entirely optional, and only used to support interactive search. They are not used by Maven for artifact retrieval.  To see if the remote publishes a search index try retrieving ".index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties" from it.

If Maven cont' download artifacts from the repository see here for information on how to diagnose the issue:

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464518-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Download-Failures

Again, artifact download failures have nothing to do with search indexes.